# Android How to add ActionBar inside linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

How do you add an actionbar inside of a RelativeLayout? I'm using actionbarSherlock to add an action bar but I cant figure out how to add it inside of a linear layout. The reason is I want to add some elements above the actionbar and below it.

edit:

Using [this library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) I can make a panel with another view slide up from the bottom. But the issue is that the actionbar stays attached at the top. Here is the code to make 2 panels in the layout.xml

```
    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:panelHeight="68dp"
        sothree:shadowHeight="4dp">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Main Content"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativtwo">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:text="The Awesome Sliding Up Panel"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

This is what I tried but didnt work still

```
     <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            sothree:panelHeight="68dp"
            sothree:shadowHeight="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/relativeone">

//I tried to place the menu in here but its completely wrong
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" />
</menu>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Main Content"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/relativtwo">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:text="The Awesome Sliding Up Panel"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

        </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Comment: the actionbar should be the top most element in your app. that being said no you cannot unless you create your own sort of view

Answer (score 0):

can you show what is that you are working on? This is almost similar [Custom action bar in relative layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261385/custom-action-bar-relative-layout-children-not-placed-correctly)

Comment: I am trying to make this library attach an actionbar to one of the views https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: Nice library! I can only think if now is,you can create multiple hierarchy of views/layout to put the elements.As described in the github example you need two child to your main slide panel layout.[Custom components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).This can be also helpful.